# Change layout of XML - split XML element values into multiply elements; remove unnecessary elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have such XML:

```
<StockInfo>
<Item>
<stockcode>111111</stockcode>
<vehicle>Ford</vehicle>
<model>Escape (2000-)~Maverick (2001-)</model>
<width>8</width>
<wheel_size>18</wheel_size>
<offset>35</offset>
<bolt_pattermn>5x114.3</bolt_pattermn>
<brand>ANTERA</brand>
<Velg_ID/>
<kit1>DK-135259671 x1</kit1>
<kit2/>
<kit3/>
<kit4/>
<qty_available>3.00000000</qty_available>
<price>1110.00</price>
<picture>410110
</picture>
</Item>
<Item>
<stockcode>111111</stockcode>
<vehicle>Honda</vehicle>
<model>Civic (5skr,2001-2006)(2006-)~Accord (2003-2008)~Acord Coupe (1999-)~Acord Type R~Civic Type R (2001-2006)(2007-,17"&lt;)~Civic Type S (2001-2006)(2007-,17"&lt;)~Integra Type R~Prelude (1997-2001)~Legend (1991-1999)</model>
<width>8</width>
<wheel_size>18</wheel_size>
<offset>40</offset>
<bolt_pattermn>5x114.3</bolt_pattermn>
<brand>ANTERA</brand>
<Velg_ID/>
<kit1>DK-135259641 x1</kit1>
<kit2/>
<kit3/>
<kit4/>
<qty_available>3.00000000</qty_available>
<price>1110.00</price>
<picture>410110
</picture>
</Item>
<Item>
<stockcode>2222222</stockcode>
<vehicle>BMW</vehicle>
<model>6 (e63/64, 2004-2011)~M6 (e63/64, 2004-2011)</model>
<width>9</width>
<wheel_size>18</wheel_size>
<offset>15</offset>
<bolt_pattermn>5x120</bolt_pattermn>
<brand>AEZ</brand>
<Velg_ID>AEZ Ares</Velg_ID>
<kit1>DK-ZJB3 x1</kit1>
<kit2/>
<kit3/>
<kit4/>
<qty_available>4.00000000</qty_available>
<price>151110.00</price>
<picture>41001
</picture>
</Item>
</StockInfo>
```

As You see there is 2 identical items (with the same stockcode; item is car wheel) and 1 different item... The same item can be X times into XML for every different car model (if this wheel is suitable for Audi A3, Audi A4, Citroen X, it will be 3 times into XML, all other elements (except  and  have the same value)).

My questions:

1. How to separate/split element `<model>`:

   ```
    <model>Civic (5skr,2001-2006)(2006-)~Accord (2003-2008)~Acord Coupe (1999-)~Acord Type R~Civic Type R (2001-2006)(2007-,17"&lt;)~Civic Type S (2001-2006)(2007-,17"&lt;)~Integra Type R~Prelude (1997-2001)~Legend (1991-1999)</model>
   ```

into X elements `<model>`

```
    <model>Civic (5skr,2001-2006)(2006-)</model>
    <model>Accord (2003-2008)</model>
    <model>Acord Coupe (1999-)</model>
    <model>Acord Type R</model>
    <model>Civic Type R (2001-2006)(2007-,17"&lt;)</model>
    <model>Civic Type S (2001-2006)(2007-,17"&lt;)</model>
    <model>Integra Type R</model>
    <model>Prelude (1997-2001)</model>
    <model>Legend (1991-1999)</model>
```

Separating symbol is "~"

Till now I was not able to do it (neither using php, neither xsl transformation) therefore looking for help ;-(

1. How To group items with identical `<stockode>` into 1 `<Item>` root instead of X?
2. How to remove elements with identical values (as I said, if wheel is suitable for many car models then it will be in the XML many times with different just  element (sometimes also `<vehicle>` - but just in case when this wheel is suitable just for few car models))?

So the modified XML should look:

```
<StockInfo>
<Item>
<stockcode>111111</stockcode>
<vehicle>Ford</vehicle>
<model>Escape (2000-)~Maverick (2001-)</model>
<vehicle>Ford</vehicle>
<model>Civic (5skr,2001-2006)(2006-)</model>
<model>Accord (2003-2008)</model>
<model>Acord Coupe (1999-)</model>
<model>Acord Type R</model>
<model>Civic Type R (2001-2006)(2007-,17"&lt;)</model>
<model>Civic Type S (2001-2006)(2007-,17"&lt;)</model>
<model>Integra Type R</model>
<model>Prelude (1997-2001)</model>
<model>Legend (1991-1999)</model>
<wheel_size>18</wheel_size>
<offset>35</offset>
<offset>40</offset>
<bolt_pattermn>5x114.3</bolt_pattermn>
<brand>ANTERA</brand>
<Velg_ID/>
<qty_available>3.00000000</qty_available>
<price>1110.00</price>
<picture>410110
</picture>
</Item>
<Item><stockcode>2222222</stockcode>
<vehicle>BMW</vehicle>
<model>6 (e63/64, 2004-2011)</model>
<model>M6 (e63/64, 2004-2011)</model>
<model>M6 (e63/64, 2004-2011)</model>
<width>9</width>
<wheel_size>18</wheel_size>
<offset>15</offset>
<bolt_pattermn>5x120</bolt_pattermn>
<brand>AEZ</brand>
<Velg_ID>AEZ Ares</Velg_ID>
<qty_available>4.00000000</qty_available>
<price>151110.00</price>
<picture>41001
</picture>
</Item>
</StockInfo>
```

Comment: Edited post to be more clear my questions!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (as solution to my 1st question):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()[contains(.,'~')]">  
<xsl:variable name="elementName" select="name(..)"/>
<xsl:call-template name="splitIntoElements">
<xsl:with-param name="baseName" select="name(..)" />
<xsl:with-param name="txt" select="." />    
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="splitIntoElements">
<xsl:param name="baseName" />
<xsl:param name="txt" />
<xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'~'" />
<xsl:variable name="first" select="substring-before($txt, $delimiter)" />
<xsl:variable name="remaining" select="substring-after($txt, $delimiter)" />
<xsl:element name="{$baseName}">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$first">
<xsl:value-of select="$first" />
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="$txt" />
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:element>
<xsl:if test="$remaining">
<xsl:call-template name="splitIntoElements">
<xsl:with-param name="baseName" select="$baseName" />
<xsl:with-param name="txt" select="$remaining" />
<xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter" />
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="model">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: it is taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657682/xslt-to-copy-over-all-nodes-and-split-on-delimiter and with small modifications according to my xml!